# persist a particular redux-form state using redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-persist

I have correctly set up redux-persist in my app. Everything is working smoothly. I was wondering how to persist redux-form's form reducer but only for a particular form, that means... whitelisting only a subset of all the forms in the application. I tried following the documentation about nested persist reducers but i get the error: 'state.setIn' is not a function'. If i persist the entire form state, it works but i don't want to persist ALL app forms. Just one in particular.

This is my root reducer:

```
const formPersistConfig = {
  key: 'form',
  storage: storage,
  transforms: [immutableTransform()]
}

return {
    i18n: i18nReducer,
    toastr: toastrReducer,
    session,
    router: routerReducer,
    form: persistReducer(formPersistConfig, formReducer),
    ...asyncReducers
}
```

That returns the root reducer which in turn is then processed like this:

```
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, 
combineReducers(makeRootReducer()))
```

And all the other code from the redux-persist lib documentation... and voila. Of course this doesn't work, it fails around @@redux-form/INITIALIZE action

Comment: When you said you tried using nested persistence, what did you do? Can you post your code where you tried that?